# Using Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim to trim a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to Trim a range of cells using the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim`.  I'm trying to define my range, but I get a type mismatch error

I created Dim and set my range and created a variable for the function.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim myanswer

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T10")
myanswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)
```

Here's another one of my codes

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("T2:T" & LastRow)

Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim (rng)
```

I want it to trim each of cells to get rid extra spaces.

Also tried using this but get out of memory.

```
rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells.Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trim()` expects string argument. The argument in `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim  (rng)` is a Range, which can be parsed to a string, only if the range consists of a single cell.

To `Trim()` all cells in a given range, they should be looped:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5")
        myCell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(myCell)
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: This works. thanks. so the WorksheetFunction is for a single cell. ok, I see.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because you need to loop through each cell, you can't do them all in one go

```
Dim rng As Range, r as range
Dim myanswer

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T10")
for each r in rng    
     r.value=Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(r)
next r
```

You can avoid a loop using Evaluate

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("T2:T10")

r = Evaluate("IF(" & r.Address & "="""","""",TRIM(" & r.Address & "))")

End Sub
```

Note that the worksheet function TRIM removes superfluous internal spaces whereas VBA Trim only removes leading and trailing spaces (you had this covered anyway).

Comment: On my large dataset the loop to 43 sec while Evaluate finished in the blink of an eye

Answer (score 4):

Although an old question there seems to be a real [quick way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257769/using-the-undocumented-application-trim) to do this. The `VBA.Trim`, `WorksheetFunction.Trim` only accept strings as input but `Application.Trim` does accept a range as input.

So instead of  `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim (rng)` you just use `Application.Trim (rng)`.