# Using the undocumented `Application.Trim` and understand VBA intellisense suggestions

Tags: excel, vba, trim

When I googled about `Trim`, I found that it is an Excel function and also a VBA function.

In VBA with both cases it can be used only with one cell and need looping with a range of more than one cell. But, I found some web pages stating use of `Application.Trim` on a range without loop and indeed it works and very fast.

My question, how `Trim` used with `Application`, even undocumented and vba intellisense does not show TRIM after I type Application. And does this mean that `WorksheetFunction.` can be replaced by `Application.` to produce a different behavior?

```
Sub Trim_Issue()
 
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3")
 
   rng = Application.Trim(rng) 'This works although I do not know how
 
   rng = WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng) 'cause error as it need loop
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `undocumented` - it's not undocumented, they just [work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064104/11683).

Comment: @GSerg ,please provide link to MS documentation itself.

Comment: @Soma https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/worksheet-function-in-vb-macro#more-information, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/not-all-excel-worksheet-functions-are-supported-as-methods-of-the-application-object-in-visual-basic-for-applications-14f231ca-5378-6bfa-a848-5ecb8d1e1ab0.

Comment: The VBA Trim function (`VBA.Trim` or just `Trim`) and the Worksheet Function TRIM (`WorksheetFunction.Trim`) are two different functions. WorksheetFunction is a member of the Application class so can also be called as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim` or, as you did, `Application.Trim`.

For Microsoft documentation for your function search for `WorksheetFunction.Trim`. And you can also search for the difference between calling it using or omitting the `Application` part (has to do with error handling).

Comment: A considerable difference: The Worksheet function trims **all** white spaces *except single white spaces* between words, whereas the VBA function only trims white spaces at the start or end of the string.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)` is the same as `WorksheetFunction.Trim(rng)` ,So it will raise **Type mismatch error** if **rng** contains more than one cell

Comment: @T.M.  when I used the VBA function `Application.Trim(rng)` ,then it trims all white spaces except single white spaces between words (exactly like The Worksheet function)

Comment: @RonR `VBA.Trim` is not mentioned at all. The question is about the difference in how `WorksheetFunction.Trim` works when called as `WorksheetFunction.Trim` vs when called as `Application.Trim`. The difference is not only in how it handles errors (which was [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257769/using-the-undocumented-application-trim-and-understand-vba-intellisence-sugges#comment129377854_73257769)), but also in that the latter is happy to accept a `Range` and return a `Variant()`, whereas the former accepts `String`, even though they are supposedly the same function.

Comment: @Soma yes, those two are equivalent.

Comment: It is the difference of early or late binding.  WorksheetFuntion.Trim is early bound which means that it has intelisense and will be compiled before running the sub and any errors stop the code unless other error handling is provided.  And for some reason early bound worksheetfunctions throw errors when using arrays , it is not allowed, unless they are native array like worksheetfunction.sumproduct.  Late bound do not get compiled until the sub is run and does not have intelisense.  The function is run and any error are passed to the output and does not stop. IDK of any documentation on it.

Comment: @Soma Your first sentence *"When I googled about Trim, I found that it is an* **Excel function** and **also VBA function**." was misleading to some extent 
as you refer `Trim` not only to the Excel, but also to the VBA library calling it a "VBA function".
It's now clear, however that your question was definitely aimed at clarifying the difference between 
the different ways (early vs late-bound) of calling only the ►WorksheetFunction `Trim` (c.f. GSerg 's helpful comments), not of `VBA.Trim`. 
(Side note: VBA.Trim would be an element of the VBA.Strings class).

Answer (score 3):

### `Application.Trim`

- My little investigation has led me to believe that `Application.Trim` actually works with arrays and returns a one-based array of the trimmed values.
- If `rng` is a contiguous range with more than one cell, the expression `rng.Value` (on the right side of an equation) is actually a 2D one-based array containing the values in the range.

**Range**

```
Sub TrimShort()
 
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3")
    ' The expression 'rng = Application.Trim(rng)' is short for:
    rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng.Value)
 
End Sub

Sub TrimLong()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3")
    ' Note that the following line is inaccurate
    ' i.e. it will fail if the range contains one cell only.
    Dim Data1() As Variant: Data1 = rng.Value
    Dim Data2() As Variant: Data2 = Application.Trim(Data1)
    rng.Value = Data2
 
End Sub
```

**Arrays**

```
Sub TrimOneD()
    
    Dim sArr() As String: sArr = Split(" A A ,  B  B", ",") ' 1D zero-based
    
    Dim dArr() As Variant: dArr = Application.Trim(sArr) ' 1D one-based
    
    Debug.Print "srIndex", "sArr", "dArr"
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 0 To UBound(sArr)
        Debug.Print r, sArr(r), dArr(r + 1)
    Next r

End Sub

Sub TrimTwoD()
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To 1, 0 To 1) ' 2D zero-based
    sData(0, 0) = " A A "
    sData(0, 1) = "  B  B"
    sData(1, 0) = " D   D "
    sData(1, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' it will not fail if error value
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = Application.Trim(sData) ' 2D one-based
    
    Debug.Print "srIndex", "scIndex", "sData", "dData"
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 0 To UBound(sData, 1)
        For c = 0 To UBound(sData, 2)
            Debug.Print r, c, sData(r, c), dData(r + 1, c + 1)
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

**Results**

```
srIndex        sArr          dArr
 0             A A          A A
 1              B  B        B B

srIndex       scIndex       sData         dData
 0             0             A A          A A
 0             1              B  B        B B
 1             0             D   D        D D
 1             1            Error 2042    Error 2042
```